# How to get pre-registered places near my location on Android without needing to display a map?

Tags: android, location, maps

I need to create an app that uses the user location to get places near the user without using the map, just the API. To reach this objective, I need to have pre-registered places (defined by me) and only the closest places to the user will be returned. What kind of approach or things that I have to do to do this feature?